# How can I write a Behat step that will capture a screenshot from the Goutte driver?

Tags: php, screenshot, behat, goutte

I need to save the HTML in a file somewhere so it can be opened in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Then /^show me the page$/
 */
public function show_me_the_page() {

    $html = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getContent();
    file_put_contents('/tmp/behat_page.html', $html);
}
```